# How to get Ionic Pro Deploy to download latest version on first app open

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

#### Problem

When I release a new version to the production channel in Ionic Pro Deploy (Channels) then I have to cycle my app twice in order to get the latest version. Even worse, on the first cycle my app reverts back to a far earlier version for some reason.

What I mean by cycling is, starting from a state where the application is shut down and not open, I open the app, wait for the splash screen to go away and app to be ready, and then close the app.

#### Question

How do I get my app to download the latest version on the very next time I open the Ionic app following my production release?

#### Plugin configuration

I used the plugin config from the dashboard.ionicjs.com page:

    `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic --save \
    --variable APP_ID="[myappid]" \
    --variable CHANNEL_NAME="Production" \
    --variable UPDATE_METHOD="background"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the command you already showed but set UPDATE_METHOD to "auto"

If you wand more control over your updating methods have a look at this: 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/deploy/plugin-api.html

Comment: I've updated config.xml UPDATE_METHOD = auto. However, on app download it doesn't install live updates. If I close the app and restart then live updates are installed.

Comment: then the downloaded binary is probably still set to "background". 
You need to build a new package and download that binary. 
The Update-process is defined in the binary. changing the config.xml  and downloading an old binary version won't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, live deploy worked correctly on a "blank" Ionic project. Live deploy also worked correctly on "my" app on iOS but not on Android.

I followed the follow steps and successfully fixed Android. However, during this process iOS suddenly had the same problem (would apply update on app install/close/open).

1. Set versions as per Ionic support. IonicPro live deploy currently requires these versions. Ionic are in the process of fixing this dependency:

   "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "1.1.19",
   "cordova-plugin-ionic": "4.1.7",
2. Install a new version of "blank" project. Update my app to use the same npm plugin versions (some of my app plugins were old).
3. Remove/add android platform. My hunch is this is what ultimately resolved the issue.

I wanted to try a remove/add ios platform to see if that also resolved the issue on iOS. But it was less work to ultimately switch over to IonicPro rather than re-config the local build setup.

Live deploy worked correctly on both iOS and Android after creating binaries in IonicPro.